# In 19th century, why was it grammatical to place "such" after its referent? But UNgrammatical in 2023, when "such" must antecede its referent?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

##### Please analyze why these examples of "such as" were grammatical — using Syntactic Theory, but in layman's terms? But why are they UNgrammatical to the [Anglophones](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/106200) I polled in 2023?

I lighted upon these sentences [here.](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/such-as)

> [Luria afterwards gave to the Sabbath a mystic beauty **such as** it had never before possessed.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Luria,_Isaac_ben_Solomon)

1. For my money, "such" was misplaced. "such" ought to antecede its referent ("a mystic beauty")!

> 1.1. [. . .] the Sabbath ***[SUCH]*** a mystic beauty <s>**such**</s> as it had never before possessed.

---

> [Such a state of things might seem degradation to the Mussulman, but it was deliverance to the native Christian, while to settlers of every kind from outside it was an opening **such as** they could hardly find elsewhere.](https://theodora.com/encyclopedia/n/normans.html)

2. This is agrammatical for such reasoning as 1. "such" ought to antecede its referent.

> 2.1. [. . .] it was ***[SUCH]*** an opening <s>**such**</s> as they could hardly find elsewhere.

I showed these examples to 3 professors (of [English descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_diaspora_in_Africa)), 4 [White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_South_Africans)  graduate students, and 19 undergraduates — all at a South African university's English department.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of South African culture, but why is the race of the professors and students relevant?

Comment: I think you may be using "grammatical" when you should be using "stylistic." There is nothing ungrammatical with using "such as" in these contexts. But if your question really is why certain persons you polled say it is so, then this question may be inappropriate here.

Comment: @alphabet: Perhaps because others are more likely to have Afrikaans or Xhosa or Hindi or some other language as their mother tongues?

Comment: @alphabet Yes. Cerberus is correct. No racism intended. Even after apartheid, alas South Africa still has racial discrimination. But if this looks racist, please edit my question to delete ethnicity from my question. South Africa has 12 official languages.

Comment: You already have [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338446/why-were-these-19th-century-uses-of-such-as-grammatical-why-are-they-ungramma) on this topic open at ELL. Please don't do that, or at least make people aware that a similar question is open elsewhere. (I'm also not sure why [you asked a similar question elsewhere on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609888/why-were-these-19th-century-uses-of-such-as-grammatical-why-are-they-ungramma). They're different, but only slightly; I'd wait for answers to this before posting such a similar question.)

Comment: @Cerberus-ReinstateMonica Makes sense. Obviously that line would sound *very* different if it came from someone in the US.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That other question has been wrongly closed as duplicate! I quoted 4 examples there, all different from the 2 here! Here, I can easily correct the ungrammaticality, by relocating **such** before the referent. But in the wrongly closed question, I can't correct the ungrammaticalities at all, even if I relocate **such**!

Comment: Since the [majority of white South Africans](https://southafrica-info.com/infographics/languages-black-coloured-indian-white-south-africans-speak/) have Afrikaans as their first language the question looks utterly ill-founded and I urge an edit. White skin doesn't automatically give you great English knowledge, as this shows.

Comment: @StuartF Ethnic background might still be relevant; I'm not an expert on the subject, but I have read that [South African English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_English) sub-dialects are named according to the different ethnicities who (at least conventionally) speak them. It's possible that the OP would have gotten differing answers if they had asked people from different backgrounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the site, that is an interesting subject.

I agree with you that *such as* after its noun sounds ever so slightly more old fashioned or formal, but it is still absolutely grammatical, and in fact fairly common.

I believe it is often stylistically preferred by good writers, when the choice presents itself. The same no doubt applies to *such that*, and perhaps others. If you search for a bit, you'll see it everywhere, not only in more or less fixed expressions, but also more freely:

[Such as they are / such as it was](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22such+as+they+are%22%7C%22such+as+it+was%22&ucbcb=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X) in Google Books.

[Such as the world has](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22such+as+the+world+has%22&ucbcb=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X) in Google Books.

**Edit:** oh, I forgot to analyse it. The word *such* is pronominal, but also adjectival; while adjectival words often come before their noun, but they can also come after, which may be considered praedicative.

> She is a worthy woman.
> She is a woman worthy of our support.

> Let each son go a different way.
> Let the sons each go a different way.

Not all adjectival words are as likely to come after, but *such + as* prefer not to be separated too far, for legibility's sake. And words as *worthy* need to come after when they have *of*, because those two words cannot be separated at all, nor can they be both placed before the noun.

The *-thing, -body,* and *-one* words also like their adjectives after:

> Something old,
> something new,
> something borrowed,
> something blue,
> and a sixpence in her shoe.

Compare *so*, which works the same way as *such*:

> I have never seen a man so old as he.

And *this/that*:

> I have never seen a man this old.

*So* and *this* modify the adjective *old*. They drag the adjective past its noun.

Also similar is *(as...) as*:

> He is as old as the world.
> He is old as the world.

Comment: As you point out, "such" in a similarly compressed sense appears in a number of nineteenth-century texts (especially religious ones) in tandem with "that." For examples, I refer you to [Google Books search results for the phrase "they are such that"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they%20are%20such%20that%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1821,cd_max:1901&lr=lang_en) for the period 1821–1901. Not all of the matches are on point, but many are.

Comment: @SvenYargs: My Google Books links are specifically from the 21st century.